# Method checks for lock, runs after lock released

Tags: javafx, locking, runnable, race-condition

Im facing a potential chase error. Im using javafx TableView to display my data, and I'm periodically receiving an update request externally which calls my update function. I also have some listeners which does stuff such as handle mousedrag events etc. What i want to do is to do something like this:

```
private void handleEvent(){
  TableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<MyModel>, TableRow<MyModel>>(){
    public TableRow<MyModel> call(TableView<MyModel> p) {
      final TableRow row = new TableRow();
      row.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        public void handle(){
          //implement some kind of lock to prevent receiving data update
        }
      }
      row.setOnMouseDragExited(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>(){
        //release lock to accept update
      }
   }
}

//this method is being called externally periodically
public void updateModel(MyModel model){
  //this won't work because it will skip entirely if it's locked,
  //I want it to instead run later when lock is released
  if (!locked){
    this.model = model;
  }
}
```

I did a quick workaround by using a Boolean to lock and unlock as shown in updateModel Method, problem with that is it will lose some updated data because it's skipped entirely.. instead, I want it to run later when lock is released.. how can I implement this kind of lock mechanism and run later feature?

Edit: why I suspect this is because my listeners are manipulating and getting table data.. while the data is constantly updated, I'm not sure if this is causing my table to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write some logic that collects everything you tried to do in a locked state and executes it on unlocking.

The following code assumes you're using `Platform.runLater` or similar code that makes the update run on the application thread.

```
public class UpdateSynchronizer {

    private final List<Runnable> pendingUpdates = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean locked = false;

    public void lock() {
        if (locked) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("double lock");
        } else {
            locked = true;
        }
    }

    public void runUpdate(Runnable updater) {
        if (updater == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (locked) {
            pendingUpdates.add(updater);
        } else {
            updater.run();
        }
    }

    public void unlock() {
        for (Runnable r : pendingUpdates) {
            try {
                r.run();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(); // print but ignore
            }
        }
        pendingUpdates.clear();
        locked = false;
    }

}
```

If the last update always overwrites all the data from previous updates, simply keeping a single `Runnable` instead of a list of them would be more performant.

```
private final UpdateSynchronizer synchronizer = new UpdateSynchronizer();

// why did all the keywords start with uppercase letters (compile time error)
private void handleEvent(){
  TableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<myModel>, TableRow<myModel>>(){
    public TableRow<myModel> call(TableView<myModel> p) {
      final TableRow row = new TableRow();
      row.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        public void handle(){
           synchronizer.lock();
           //implement some kind of lock to prevent receiving data update
        }
      }
      row.setOnMouseDragExited(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>(){
        //release lock to accept update
        synchronizer.unlock();
      }
   }
}

//this method is being called externally periodically
public void updateModel(myModel model){
  synchronizer.runUpdate(() -> {
      // this is just an assignment and won't have any side effects
      // updates to the scene may only happen, if the model is accessed in some event handler or animation
      this.model = model;

  });
}
```

Comment: Great! This looks like what I want. But I'm unfamiliar with run later and still confused after reading online.. do i simply place "synchronized.runUpdate(()->{//method});" within "Platform.runLater(New Runnable(){}"?

Comment: `Platform.runLater(() -> synchronized.runUpdate(() -> { /* do update */}))`

Comment: Splendid! Thank you so much!